# Windows Phone 8.1 - Converters do not work using platform target ARM

Tags: c#, arm, winrt-xaml, converters, windows-phone-8.1

I've developed app on windows phone 8.1. Several of my pages have the custom converter; for example:

```
 using System;
 using System.Globalization;
 using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

 namespace XXXXX.Model.Converters
 {
     public sealed class DateTimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
     {
         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
         {
             var date = (DateTime)value;

             return date.ToString("g", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
         }

         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
         {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
         }
     }
 }
```

In the XAML i have:

```
 <Page
     x:Class="XXXXX.Views.VehiclesView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     xmlns:converters="using:XXXXX.Model.Converters"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
     Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">

     <Page.Resources>
         <converters:DateTimeToStringConverter x:Key="DateTimeToStringConverter" />
         <converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" />
     </Page.Resources>
```

And use it in this way:

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Distance, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0} Km'}"></TextBlock>
```

1) Why does the compiler gives me this error?

```
 The name "DateTimeToStringConverter" does not exist in the namespace using:XXXXX.Model.Converters
```

2) Why does it work if I change the target platform to x86?

3) If I wanted to work in XAML and not in Code Behind, are there alternatives to the Converter?

Comment: Make sure that your converter in the same assembly

Comment: try without ConverterParameter and without CultureInfo. also just public class. And clean the project and make rebuild. Although in appearance everything right.

Comment: Can you try rebuilding?

Comment: @Dmitry Dashko: yes the Converter is in the same Assembly!

Comment: @igrali: I rebuild solution many times, but the problem remain.

Comment: @IceFog: I try without ConvertParameter but doesn't work. The problem persist. The VisualStudio exception on XAML is: **"The name StringFormatConverter does not exist in the namespace using:XXX.Model.Converters"**. If I change Target Platform from ARM to x86 works. Not work with Target Platform ARM.

Comment: I found this link [Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/34aeb1ac-d47c-470b-8b72-acfb2b94a41d/converter-does-not-exist-in-namespace-even-though-it-exists-in-namespace?forum=winappswithcsharp) which shows the same problem. The answer says: **the problem here is that you are building using Platform Target x64 which is not supported by the XAML Designer, as designer is a 32 bit (x86) process**. Do you think there is an alternative to the problem or do I have to handle it in the view model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to move converters in dedicate class library with target platform "AnyCPU", and reference it in your application project.

Comment: Can you explain why it needs to be in a separate  library?

Comment: The converters use using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data; and in the library project this reference is not available or needs to be added. How is this done?

Some help here please :)